# Appium Android Automation

Tags: android, appium, mobile-application

This may be simple question for the experts. I am a beginner in appium and all these days i have been trying to make my test script for printing a page title in my script. Here is the part of  My code below: i am unable to print the page title and then do a validation. Can someone help?

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      System.out.println(driver.getRemoteAddress()); 
}

public void ApkPushValidation() throws Exception {

Assert.assertEquals("Verify your phone number", driver.findElementByName("Verify your phone number").getText());

    driver.wait(5000);
    String i = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(i);


if (driver.getTitle().equals("Verify your phone number") ) {

    System.out.println("app installation is passed");

} else {

System.out.println("App installation is failed");

}

//System.out.println(i);---> my expectation is that this will print out Verify your Phone number. However this is not printing the page title.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UIAutomatorViewer to find out the xpath of the title.

use the following website for example on how to use the x-path. "http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.ca/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html"

Answer (score 0):

I think that `driver.getTitle()` is a method for Web page interaction, not meant for Native apps. I would suggest to use XPath or some other element locator to find the title.

Comment: Are you saying that adding a driver.wait before find element by name?. If yes then it also did not work. I am getting below console error after running:

Comment: FAILED: ApkPushTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: The log you provided is confirming my suspicion. This method is not intended for use yet.

Comment: Thanks @Kristaps Mezavilks.As you rightly said getTitle() method is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Instead if `getTitle();` try to use xPath, name or Id available for the title. Use Appium inspector or UI automator to locate that element and change it like this:

```
String i = driver.findElementById("Your ID").getText();
if (i.equals("Verify your phone number") ) {
    System.out.println("app installation is passed");

} else {

System.out.println("App installation is failed");

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Well i used AssertEquals method to verify the expected string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably what to perform should be done using the following piece of code :

```
WebElement title = driver.findElementByName("Verify your phone number"); // defining the element only once for multiple use
// different locator strategies could be used for locating the element above

Assert.assertEquals("Verify your phone number", title.getText());  
driver.wait(5000);
String i = title.getText();
System.out.println(i);    
if (i.equals("Verify your phone number") ) {
    System.out.println("app installation is passed");
} else {
    System.out.println("App installation is failed");
}
```

More on `driver.getTitle()` : It has been inherited from `RemoteWebDriver` and possibly should return the title of a webpage/webview instead of an native application view which seems to be your case.

***Note***: would add more to this about getTitle() as I get to know.